# Docker container memory limits

Tags: docker, memory, containers

is there a way to set the minimum memory limit for a docker container? I know that `-m` option sets the max limit but is there something similar for the min?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this would mean.  Are you trying to force a dockerized application to utilize some amount of memory?  I would expect that to be a param to set on the actual application, not something for docker itself.  You can lead the application to RAM, but you can't make it alloc.

Comment: the thing is that there are multiple services running on the same machine,, I just wanted to make sure that one of them does not take over the resources

Comment: Kubernetes is a much more complex environment, but its notion of resource requests might fit this specific need.